When ever I start my Java Rest Application, it creates old replaced columns in my MySQL table
I built a Java 18, Spring boot, Rest API that retrieves data from a MySQL database.  I recently decided to change a few of the database table column names to better represent the fields.  But whenever I start my rest application it adds back in the old columns I removed to my database table.
For example:
I added the following columns to my table:
examName
examCost
Then I dropped the following columns in the same table:
exam_name
exam_cost
But know when I start my application it creates exam_name and exam_cost adding them to table again.
(When I ran the Alter table command to drop them from the table, I always commit afterwards and check run a describe to be sure.
I am using the following:
Java 18
Spring boot
Maven
MySQL
Here is my application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tests
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXXXXXXXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Here is my Controller class:
package com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.controller;

import com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.model.Question;
import com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.service.QuestionService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ready-set-cert-api")
public class CertTesterController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionService questionService;

    @Autowired
    public CertTesterController(QuestionService questionService) {
        this.questionService = questionService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/healthcheck")
    public ResponseEntity healthCheckMessage() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/exam/question/add")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addQuestion(@RequestBody Question question) {
        questionService.addQuestion(question);
        return "Exam Name: '" + question.getExamName() + "', Question Number: '" + question.getQuestionNumber() + "' has been Saved.";
    }
}

Here is my model class:
package com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;

@Entity
@Table(name = "examquestions")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String examName;
    @Column
    private Integer questionNumber;
    @Column
    private String question;
    @Column
    private String scenario;
    @Column
    private String choice_1;
    @Column
    private String choice_2;
    @Column
    private String choice_3;
    @Column
    private String choice_4;
    @Column
    private String choice_5;
    @Column
    private String answer;
    @Column
    private String why;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getExamName() {
        return examName;
    }

    public void setExamName(String examName) {
        this.examName = examName;
    }

    public int getQuestionNumber() {
        return questionNumber;
    }

    public void setQuestionNumber(Integer questionNumber) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getScenario() {
        return scenario;
    }

    public void setScenario(String scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    public String getChoice_1() {
        return choice_1;
    }

    public void setChoice_1(String choice_1) {
        this.choice_1 = choice_1;
    }

    public String getChoice_2() {
        return choice_2;
    }

    public void setChoice_2(String choice_2) {
        this.choice_2 = choice_2;
    }

    public String getChoice_3() {
        return choice_3;
    }

    public void setChoice_3(String choice_3) {
        this.choice_3 = choice_3;
    }

    public String getChoice_4() {
        return choice_4;
    }

    public void setChoice_4(String choice_4) {
        this.choice_4 = choice_4;
    }

    public String getChoice_5() {
        return choice_5;
    }

    public void setChoice_5(String choice_5) {
        this.choice_5 = choice_5;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getWhy() {
        return why;
    }

    public void setWhy(String why) {
        this.why = why;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", examName='" + examName + '\'' +
                ", questionNumber='" + questionNumber + '\'' +
                ", question='" + question + '\'' +
                ", scenario='" + scenario + '\'' +
                ", choice_1='" + choice_1 + '\'' +
                ", choice_2='" + choice_2 + '\'' +
                ", choice_3='" + choice_3 + '\'' +
                ", choice_4='" + choice_4 + '\'' +
                ", choice_5='" + choice_5 + '\'' +
                ", answer='" + answer + '\'' +
                ", why='" + why + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

Here is my repository class:
package com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.Repository;

import com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.model.Question;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Integer> {

}

Here is my service class:
package com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.service;

import com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.Repository.QuestionRepository;
import com.anyone.ready_set_cert_api.model.Question;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class QuestionService {

    private final QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    public QuestionService(QuestionRepository questionRepository) {

        this.questionRepository = questionRepository;
    }
    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void addQuestion(Question question) {
        questionRepository.save(question);
    }

    public void deleteQuestion(int id) {
        for (int x = 0; x < questions.size(); x++) {
            if (questions.get(x).getId() == id) {
                questions.remove(questions.get(x));
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is my pom file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mctigue</groupId>
    <artifactId>ready-set-cert-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ready-set-cert-api</name>
    <description>Java, Spring Boot, MySQL Rest API application to help people study for certifications.</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
        <start-class>com.mctigue.ready_set_cert_api.ReadySetCertApiApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Here is the JSON data I'm using in Postman to test it:
endpoint:
http://localhost:8080/ready-set-cert-api/exam/question/add
{
    "id": 102,
    "examName": "Python PCEP Certification Preparation Test",
    "questionNumber": 5,
    "question": "Which of the following is incorrect for a dictionary in Python?",
    "scenario": "empty scenario",
    "choice_1": "each key must be unique", 
    "choice_2": "the key should be an immutable object", 
    "choice_3": "the len() function returns the sum of key-value elements in the dictionary", 
    "choice_4": "the len() function returns the numbers of key-value elements in the dictionary",
    "choice_5": "empty choice",
    "answer": "the len() function returns the sum of key-value elements in the dictionary",
    "why": "because the world is round"
}

Here is the error from intellij:
2024-09-05T17:49:12.292-04:00 ERROR 7020 --- [ready-set-cert-api] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'questionNumber' doesn't have a default value
2024-09-05T17:49:12.315-04:00 ERROR 7020 --- [ready-set-cert-api] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement [Field 'questionNumber' doesn't have a default value] [insert into examquestions (answer,choice_1,choice_2,choice_3,choice_4,choice_5,exam_name,question,question_number,scenario,why,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'questionNumber' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:912) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1054) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1312) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:988) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.performNonBatchedMutation(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.performNonBatchedOperations(MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.execute(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinatorStandard.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinatorStandard.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinatorStandard.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinatorStandard.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinatorStandard.insert(InsertCoordinatorStandard.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:632) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:499) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:487) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2324) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1981) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:795) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:758) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:663) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:413) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy119.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mctigue.ready_set_cert_api.service.QuestionService.addQuestion(QuestionService.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mctigue.ready_set_cert_api.controller.CertTesterController.addQuestion(CertTesterController.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.28.jar:10.1.28]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

I appreciate any help on understanding what went wrong on this.

I am not sure but maybe this has to do something with the naming strategy of Hibernate. It may convert lowerCamelCase to snake_case.
Maybe add jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl to your application.yml.
Otherwise you could try giving explicit names via @Column(name = "columnName")

Hibernate by default create column name based on java attribute name (and convert it to snack case) because java attribute name follows camelCase and are case sensitive but database table columns follow snack_case and are case insensitive so:
questionNumber attribute will be created as question_number column you can change it with @Column annotation like this:
@Column("column_name_that_you_want")
private Integer attributeName;

for your case if you also want column name same as attribute name than you can do like this:
@Column("questionNumber")
private Integer questionNumber;


Thank you, this absolutely correct and was the answer to my situation.

I solve my dilemma, I didn't realize my camel case field variables in my model classes were being converter under the covers to variables with underscores.
Example:
In my model class my variable would be
"examName"
But when using JPA with a built-in repository
It converts this field to "exam_name".
Once I realized this I was able to change all my camel case field values in my database to underscore field variables so the result of the automatic conversion would match.
All is good now .
